# How to use a ToggleButton to change input type of TextView every time the ToggleButton is clicked?

Tags: android, textview, togglebutton

I have a `ToggleButton` which I want to change the input type of a `TextView` every time the button is clicked. I want the input type of the text view to toggle between password and normal text every time I click the button. But what's happening is, upon clicking the button, the input type of the text view is changing from password type to normal text. But that's about it. When I click the button after the first time, no change in input type takes place in the text view. I know I am not doing something here but due to my lack of Android knowledge and experience I can't seem to solve the puzzle.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

```
public class TextPlay extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // map the views
        final EditText commandInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
        final ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);

        // set listeners on the button
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
                    commandInput
                            .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    commandInput.refreshDrawableState();
                } else {
                    commandInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Specifically this section:

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

I think using the current way you are trying, you could just change it to:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
            commandInput
                    .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            commandInput.refreshDrawableState();
        } else {
            toggleButton.setChecked(true);
            commandInput
                    .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        }

    }
```

Paying attention to the `setChecked(true);` line.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your response. I have tried your suggested code out but it doesn't seem to achieve the desired purpose. The EditText object doesn't change the text from normal text to password and back to normal text when the ToggleButton is clicked multiple times. Also 'setChecked(true);' doesn't actually toggle the state of the ToggleButton. In fact it keeps the ToggleButton toggled on all the time.

Comment: isChecked does not get called! @Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TextPlay extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    final ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    final TextView disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);

    input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (passTog.isChecked()) {
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            } else {
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answers!